# To fetch a specific sentence in a given string

Tags: c#

The example string is shown below.

> "{"This is the allstate company url":{"previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/allstate/feedaccess_token=AAACEdEose24VEBPa9&limit=25&since=13369&__previous=1","the comany url fetched"}}

From the above string I want extract

> "https:\/graph.facebook.com/allstate/feedaccess_token=AAACEdEose24VEBPa9&limit=25&since=13369&__previous=1"

How to do that? In my real case I have many sentences before and after the string which I need to fetch .

Comment: Didn't you ask this question three hours ago already and got downvoted a lot?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: yes - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547565/how-to-select-and-save-a-sentence-in-a-double-qoutes-and-discard-the-remaining-s

Comment: @marc_s: Found it, too, was just looking for it. Original Poster: I suggest you rephrase your question so that we see a minimum amount of effort. We're not here to write your software - show us what you've tried and we can help you then.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), it can parse your JSON string to a meaningful object which you can then interact with in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the text can differ. If it is always https and there is always a comma after the url you can use this regex:

### .*"(https://.+)",.*

```
string strUrl = string.Empty;
string strPattern = @".*"(https://.+)",.*";
Match match = Regex.Match(strLine, strPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
  strUrl = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

There are good tools in the internet to develop reges expressions.
as example [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)